# Visual Studio 2010 only x86 build option?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to compile my application for 64 bit, but in the options I only have x86 everywhere?  I've looked in all the places but there's only x86 and no 64 bit at all.

Here's what I mean.

[image]

There's no options for 64 bit in configuration manager that I can find.  Note that this is the Express edition, not the retail edition.

Comment: What is type of project? Do you have multi targeting installed?

Comment: What Visual Studio Editon are you using?

Comment: That's really weird then. It works perfectly for me and I have just the Express edition.

Comment: This is an option that only matters for C++ projects.  Getting the 64-bit C++ compilers is an option you have to select at install time.  Why did you tag it C#?  If it is really a C# project then just change the Platform target in the Build tab from x86 to AnyCPU.

Comment: I have the express edition.  What's multi targeting?

@Hans I just said in the post, and even posted a picture, there is no AnyCPU or anything except x86.

Comment: Yes, that option is not exposed in the Express edition.  It isn't shown in the dropdown that's in your screenshot anyway.  You can edit the .csproj file by hand if you really want to, `<PlatformTarget>` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let people know if they stumble across this, XNA has no 64 bit support at all which is why I couldn't do it.

Comment: Don't have xna but the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 5):

**To configure your project's target on a 64-bit platform, you can use the configuration manager in Visual Studio.**

Here are the steps:

1. *Go to Build menu*
2. *Select Configuration Manager*
3. *In the Active solution platform list, select the 64-bit platform for the solution to target.*
4. *If you do not see the option, select New*
5. *In the New Solution Platform dialog box, select the 64-bit platform for the solution to target.*
6. *Now the build of the project will be optimized for 64-bit platforms.*

I took it from the blog post *[Use Visual Studio to build 64-bit application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/03/21/use-visual-studio-to-build-64-bit-application.aspx)*.

Comment: Click confirguration manager and see if you find "AnyCPU" click that.

Comment: There is no AnyCPU, only x86.

Comment: If you go to configuration manager there will be 2 dropdown lists click the Active solution platform dropdown and select New... and type there x64 in "type or select the new platform" textbox and leave copy settings from as it is.

Comment: Thanks but I decided to reinstall VS to see if it would make a difference.

Comment: @coder, what if I can't create any other platform option, because it's already created?